# Why doesn't the proving work if the vectors change sides?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, area, cross-product

[image]

Instead of calculating the area of F4 as shown in the solution I could also calculate it by doing 1/2 (B-A)x(C-A) since for area the direction doesn't matter but if i do it this way the proving doesn't seem to work? I dont understand why? The direction of the vector isn't supposed to effect the area so i could do it either way and still the proving should work.

Comment: The problem is about vectors i.e. magnitude and direction matters. What you did does not change the magnitude but change the direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $\mathbf V_1,$ $\mathbf V_2,$ $\mathbf V_3,$ $\mathbf V_4$
> be vectors whose magnitudes are respectively equal to the areas of
> $F_1,$ $F_2,$ $F_3,$ $F_4$ and whose directions are perpendicular to those faces
> **in the outward direction**.

I have added emphasis to the words "in the outward direction."

When you write
$\frac12 (\mathbf B-\mathbf A)\times(\mathbf C-\mathbf A)$
you get a vector that is perpendicular to the bottom face of the tetrahedron
but is pointing in the **inward** direction
(to the same side of the face as the side where the rest of the tetrahedron lies) using the right-hand rule for the direction of the cross product.
So this vector does not satisfy the conditions in the statement, which say every vector must point in the **outward** direction from its face.

Comment: Ohhh yess i missed that point! Thank you sooo much